# rhel 8 php81 gd not install

Tags: php-gd, php-8.1

I have php 8.1 version on Redhat 8 RHEL Server.
**The server has no internet access. We manage it remotely with VPN.**

I can't run the "php artisan optimize" command in the application directory. it says gd and zip are not installed.

I downloaded the rpm for gd. i get the error on the screen. can you help ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0pEs.png)

https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/8/
I tried downloading common gd from the rpms on this site and unfortunately I could not install gd.